# Android TextView and text wrapping

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView inside a TableRow. The text contained in this TextView is tipically larger than the screen. As such, I would like for the the text to wrap into multiple lines.

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTable);
TableRow row = new Tablerow(context);
TextView view = new TextView(context);
view.setText(stringWithLotsOfCharacters);
view.setSingleLine(false);
row.add(view);
table.addview(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

I tried using "setSingleLine" but it does not have the effect I was looking for.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Add `android:shrinkColumns="1"` for the column you want to wrap to the **TableLayout** in your layout or `android:shrinkColumns="*"` if you want to wrap all columns.

You can also do it programmatically with setColumnShrinkable:

```
public void setColumnShrinkable (int columnIndex, boolean isShrinkable)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
view.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. The text is not appearing anymore. I just edited the first post with more of my code.

Comment: What are the `LayoutParams` of `myTable`?

Comment: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Set your `layout_width` of the table to `fill_parent` and for good measure also set your view to the same e.g. `view.setWidth(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);`.

Comment: @MattBishop this is wrong mate.. What happen in case u have more then one coloumn in a row?

Comment: Simple answer for a simple question, there's no discussion of columns here. This is also an almost 2-year-old post, Android has dramatically changed their layout recommendations since.